# Eigenvalue and span of vector in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Hilbert space $H=l^{2}( \mathbb{N} )$ and $x=\sum_{j}\frac{e_j}{j} \in H$. Consider an operator $T$ on  $l^{2}( \mathbb{N} )$ such that
\begin{align*}
T(\sum_i <z,e_i>e_i)=(\sum_i <z,e_i> |<x,e_i>|^3e_i)+k<x,z>x. 
\end{align*}
$T$ is a positive operator when restricted to span$(x)$ $^{\perp}$. We also have
\begin{align*}
 \langle T( e_j ) ,e_j \rangle =|\langle x,e_j \rangle|^{3}+k|\langle x,e_j \rangle|^{2}   
,\end{align*}
which is negative for $k<0$ and  $j$ sufficiently large. How do we conclude that  $T$ has only has 1 negative eigenvalue when $k<0$?

I think I might  have some misunderstandings about  span$(x)$. Since span$(x)$ is induced by one vector, it is closed. In the meantime,  $e_i$ can not be in span($x$) $^{\perp}$ as  $\langle e_i,x \rangle\neq 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. That would imply that $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is in span($x$). It does not seem right.

Comment: $T$ is not linear and hence we cannot speak about eigenvalues.

Comment: I assume $T$ is being understood in the sense $T(\sum_i <z,e_i>e_i)=(\sum_i <z,e_i> |<x,e_i>|^3e_i)+k<x,z>x$

Comment: Oh, I see. Then it's surely linear.

Comment: I can see why we have a negative eigenvalue on $span(x)^{\perp}$ as a result of $T(span(x)^{\perp})$ has dimension 1. I just stuck on the case when $z=u+v$ when $u$ in span$(x)$ and $v$ in span$(x)^\perp$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is the sum of a non-negative (compact) self-adjoint operator $A$ and a self-adjoint operator $F$ with one-dimensional range (and hence a kernel of codimension one). Assume that there are two negative eigenvalues of $A+F$, for example $-1$ and $-2$ (for simplicity). Then there exist corresponding unit eigenvectors $x$ and $y$, that is, $(A+F)x = -x$ and $(A+F)y = -2y$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\|y\|=1$. [Edit: this is another $x$ as yours] Since $\ker F$ is 1-codimensional and $x,y$ are linearly independent, there exist scalars $a,b$ such that $ax+by\in\ker F$. Hence,
$$
-ax-2by = a(A+F)x + b(A+F)y = A(ax+by)
$$
and therefore
$$
0\le (A(ax+by),ax+by) = (-ax-2by,ax+by) = -a^2 - 2b^2,
$$
since $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal to each other. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can see the main flow of the proof. I am wondering what is the assumption about $x$ and $y$. Are they just the eigenvectors?  Also, I did not get the part, there exists scalar $a,b$ such that $ax+by \in Ker (F)$. Would you be able to elaborate more on that?

Comment: 1. Yes, they are eigenvectors of $T+F$. 2. $\ker F$ is one-codimensional, like a 6-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^7$. Or a 2-dim subspace $M$ of $\mathbb R^3$. If you have two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, a linear combination of them will lie in $M$.

Comment: This is a really nice characterization.  The uniqueness of negative eigenvalue just follows from your arguments. Thank you.

Comment: It was a pleasure. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is by no means true that $x \notin M^{\perp}$ implies $ x\in M$ for a closed subspace $M$. ($M^{\perp}$ is not the set-theoretic complement of $M$.) For example, If $M$ is $x-$axis in $\mathbb R^{2}$ then $M^{\perp}$ is the $y-$axis. $(1,1)$ is not in $M^{\perp}$ but it is not in $M$ either.

Comment: Aha that is true. We could always write $x \in H$ in the sense of $u+v$, where $u \in M$ and $v \in M^\perp$.  That does not imply $x \in M$ or $x \in M^\perp$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am appreciated. Sorry, I decided to accept the other answer.